# Denial of service: regular expression

Tags: java, regex, fortify, denial-of-service

When we send this code to fortify scan

```
int len=inputString.length();
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("[0-9]{"+Integer.toString(len-1)+"}");
```

The second line is vulnerable to Denial of Service: regular expression.

How to resolve this issue? I tried different ways, but nothing is working out.

Comment: First, I think your security scanning tool is overly critical: This is unlikely to cause an issue. Second, even so constructing a regex at runtime is a bad habit to get into and can almost always be avoided entirely. Especially this specific use seems weird: what are you trying to do here? If you want a string to be all numbers except (for example) for the last character, simply use something like `^[0-9]*[^0-9]$` to check that, no need to construct a pattern dynamically.

Comment: @JoachimSauer `^[0-9]*[^0-9]$` probably won't work, the resulting pattern from the question is something like `[0-9]{9}` (for example), so it seems OP wants to capture numeric string with exact length. The fix is probably to validate that `len` is within some range, and to make sure it's not negative, as that would lead to some funny regex.

Comment: @Chaosfire: they use `len-1`, which my pattern also checks: all but one character must be digits.

Comment: @JoachimSauer The example in questions results in regex like this one - `[0-9]{2}`, if `len` was `3`, let's say. This regex captures *exactly* two digits. I don't see anything that suggests only digits followed by one non digit.

Comment: @Chaosfire: all of that is correct, but `len` is being set to exactly the length of the input string in the first line and assume that this input string is also what the regex is applied to.

Comment: maybe we need a [mre], or better explanation .. anyway, as I already commented, `"[0-9]{-1}"` is an invalid regular expression and will throw an exception

Comment: As a side note, the invocation of `Integer.toString` is obsolete, just `"[0-9]{"+(len-1)+"}"` would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The fortify scanner is giving a good catch on this one, reason being user supplied pattern.

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("[0-9]{"+Integer.toString(len-1)+"}");
```

Fortify see the regex pattern constructed based on user input which may result in a DoS. Even so, the resulting pattern on your case at worst will ask the app to capture 2,147,483,646 characters - an enormous number but won't result in catastrophic backtracking. However, you should keep in mind that large enough integer in the quantifier may be rejected by the regex engine.

You could rewrite the code with regex only ensuring the string consist of only integers while length checking done using the good old `String.length()`.

```
int len = inputString.length();
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+$");
if(myString.length() == len && p.matcher(myString).find())
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //fail
}
```

Also, keep in mind there are [many ways to broke regex](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

Comment: But something like `[0-9]+` would capture the same length group, so how is this any worse?

Comment: @JoachimSauer the perspective of the scanner. unrestricted user input = bad. its not about the code make sense, its about stuff to make fortify happy. i know it dumb, but some clients insist.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but you're not saying that in your answer, you're claiming that it is a DoS and not that the tool wrongly things it is a DoS. Working around restrictions of your tools is fine, but one should be aware if that's what one is doing.