# Match city name

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to check if a string contains city names.

The city name must not be proceeded or succeeded by any letters.

This works if it's in the middle of the string but it doesn't if it's at the beginning or the end (and also not if it has multiple lines).

```
String k = "new york";
messageTextLower.matches(".*[^a-z]" + Pattern.quote(k) + "[^a-z].*")
```

Comment: Try `messageTextLower.matches("(?ms).*\\b" + Pattern.quote(k) + "\\b.*");`

Comment: It's not really clear if  `k` and `messageTextLower` are both user input

Comment: What is the question? You haven't specified what is happening and what deviates from your expectations. You should provide a few samples of `messageTextLower` and the expected output in each case.

Answer (score 0):

What about using both negative lookahead and lookbehind?

```
(?<![a-z])new york(?![a-z])
```

The regex above will check that no letters actually sitting before and after the `new york`.

See Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/zw6Q1L/3

---

In a hindsight, constructing regex like this may cause serious issue if you have to [consider application security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557606/denial-of-service-regular-expression/77557666#77557666). It would be much safer to work with the good old iteration manually.

```
public static List<Integer> findOccurences(String text, String word){
    List<Integer> ls = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    
    if(text == null || word == null
       || text.trim().length() == 0
       || word.trim().length() == 0){
        return ls;
    }
    
    int idx = 0;
    int wordLength = 0;
    while(idx != -1){
        idx = text.indexOf(word, idx + wordLength);
        if(idx != -1){
            wordLength = word.length();
            
            //skips if preceeded by [a-z]
            if((idx - 1) >= 0
                && text.charAt(idx - 1) >= 'a'
                && text.charAt(idx - 1) <= 'z'){
                    continue;
            }
            
            //skip if succeeded by [a-z]
            if((idx + wordLength) < text.length()
                && text.charAt(idx + wordLength) >= 'a'
                && text.charAt(idx + wordLength) <= 'z'){
                    continue;
            }
            
            ls.add(idx);
        }
    }
    
    return ls;
}
```

See Fiddle: https://onecompiler.com/java/3zvdxdt47

There might be more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: The question does not prohibit the city name from being preceded or followed by a digit or underscore.

Comment: @CarySwoveland do special characters such as dollar sign, brackets, etc allowed?

Comment: If the second sentence of the question is read literally--how I read it, and how I believe questions should be written--the answer would be "yes", but you may wish to ask the OP.